# django formset and and initial data

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a simple model and a simple form. The form looks like this:

```
class AddForm(forms.Form):
    quantity = forms.IntegerField(label='', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'size':'2'}))
    product_id = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.HiddenInput)
```

In my template there's a object_list containing all the model-objects.
What I want is: next to each model-object a form to enter the "quantity". The "product_id"-field has to have the id of each model as initial data.
I guess I have to use Formsets for this, but I don't understand how to set the initial data from database-data and how to make Formsets display a form for each model-object.

Thanks in advance
Jacques

Answer (score 0):

As the form you want to add is so simple, it's easier just to add the product id in the template with something like

```
<input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="{{ object.id }}" />
```

rather than adding complicated formsets.